# Keep logo in left corner and centre ul elements with CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  paddingBottom: 8px;
  paddingLeft: 5px;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 40px;;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src={nicklogo} className="logo" alt="logo" />
  <ul>
    <li>Me</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>Skills</li>
  </ul>
  </header>
```

I have a header element that has an img tag and ul tag wit 3 li elements.
I have the logo in the img tag in my left corner. I want to position the 3 li elements in the centre of the header element.

I also want to make it scale when people are reading it on different size screens.

Comment: An answer already includes your code, so I don't think it's ok for me to update this question, but you can leave React out it since this is a CSS question. So instead of `src={nicklogo}` you could just write something like `src="/logo.png"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is exactly centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  padding-Bottom: 8px;
  padding-Left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 40px;;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src={nicklogo} class="logo" alt="logo" />
  <div class="center">
    <ul>
      <li>Me</li>
      <li>Projects</li>
      <li>Skills</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  paddingBottom: 8px;
  paddingLeft: 5px;
}
.logo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  
  padding-left: 10px;
}
ul {
  margin: auto;
display:block;

  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src={nicklogo} className="logo" alt="logo" />
  <ul>
    <li>Me</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>Skills</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```